# Can I leave China after entering with a 000 day Z Visa and not getting a residence permit?

Tags: visas, china

I entered China a couple weeks ago to work for a company, and it isn’t going well. If I attempt to quit and leave the country would I be stopped if I left with just my z visa or would I need to wait until I get my residence permit and then quit?

Comment: This is probably best asked on our sister site, [expatriates.se].